# Apache2 mod_proxy authentication

Tags: http, authentication, proxy, apache2, http-authentication

I have apache2 and I want to do the following thing. I want to take a request with basic authentication check it against a htpasswd file and then to proxy the request to a different http server with basic http authentication.

Is this possible without having to write some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impossible with apache2. You need to use something like mochiweb instead and do it manually.